# Duo 2 Factor Authentication - Admin API Retrieve Secret Key

Tags: python, authentication, system-administration, duosecurity

I cannot retrieve the secret key from the Duo Admin API.

I have created a Duo Admin API with the following authorizations.

- Grant Applications
- Grant Read Log
- Grant Read Resource

When looking at the Duo Admin API github ( (https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_client_python/blob/master/duo_client/admin.py)
), I don't see a specific api call for "Retrieve Secret" as it seems like there would be based on the documentation found here:
https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#retrieve-secret-key

If I perform the "get_integration" call, I am able to get the secret key, however it is only partially visible (i.e. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3432jas).

The documentation states that the python client supports this, but I don't see that functionality. Additionally, the documentation states that the authentication requests for this endpoint are signed differently than as stated in the docs...so we cannot generate the requests ourselves...

Does anyone know how to get the fully visible secret key via the admin api?